# `vsync` property in TabController constructor

Tags: dart, tabcontrol, flutter

According to this: [sample code](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController-class.html)

I created my own implementation of TabController:

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: new TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            isScrollable: false,
            tabs: choices.map((Choice choice) {
              return new Tab(
                text: null,
                icon: new Icon(choice.icon),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Swap'),
        ),
        body: new TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: choices.map((Choice choice) {
            return new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: new ChoiceCard(choice: choice),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In line: `_tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length);` I got error this message:

> error: The argument type '_MyAppState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [swap] lib/main.dart:24)

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Add `with TickerProviderStateMixin` to the end of your `State`’s class declaration.

Comment: It was that. Now Im getting weird log in console during changing tabs: `Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2257 pos 12: 'fragment is _InterestingSemanticsFragment': is not true.`

Comment: Doesn’t sound related, maybe restart app / upgrade your Flutter?

Comment: You might get hot Reload issues using StateMixin, if you do, try to use TickerProviderStateMixin instead of SingleTickerProviderStateMixin

Answer (score 42):

Simply add `with TickerProviderStateMixin` at the end of extends state class as follows:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 19):

**As Answered earlier adding the `mixin`, `TickerProviderStateMixin` should do the job or you can also use `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` if you only need a Single `Ticker`.**

> But what is Does `TickerProviders` really do?

`vsync` takes a `TickerProvider` as  an argument , that's why we use `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` and as the named describes `TickerProvider` provides `Ticker` which simply means it tells our app about the Frame update(or Screen Update), so that our `AnimationController` can generate a new value and we can redraw the animated widget.

Answer (score 12):

Add ***TickerProviderStateMixin*** at the end of class state

#### Here is the full example

```
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  MotionTabController? _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new MotionTabController(initialIndex: 1, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController!.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In GetX

I found a solution just add with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin to be the full code as the below one:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ControllerViewModel extends GetxController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 2500,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It Worked  , thanks a lot. but SingleGetTickerProviderMixin showing as deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Question is very generic, so need to describe more

**Vsync used for**

- vsync is the property that represents the TickerProvider (i.e., Tick
  is similar to clock's tick which means that at every certain duration
  TickerProvider will render the class state and redraw the object.)
- vsync property is required only on that constructor which requires to render its class state at every certain off-set time when we need to render our components or widgets to redraw and reflect the UI.
- vsync can be used with the classes which require certain transition or animation to re-render to draw different objects.

**Internal Implementation**

```
TabController({ int initialIndex = 0, @required this.length, @required TickerProvider vsync })
: assert(length != null && length >= 0),
  assert(initialIndex != null && initialIndex >= 0 && (length == 0 || initialIndex < length)),
  _index = initialIndex,
  _previousIndex = initialIndex,
  _animationController = AnimationController.unbounded(
    value: initialIndex.toDouble(),
    vsync: vsync,
  );
```

`TabController` uses `AnimationController` internally for the rendering of the tab bar state

Comment: Its really seems like that could have been an optional parameter.

Answer (score 7):

The above answers are correct but you have to declare a tabbar in class and initialize the tabbar from iniState, else the vsync variable doesn't accept '*this*'
Following code may help you.

```
class _MatchesState extends State<Matches> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
      initialIndex: 0,
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add any of these **SingleTickerProviderStateMixin**/ **TickerProviderStateMixin**  mixins at the end of the statement like below:

Eg:

> class _ListingViewState extends State with **SingleTickerProviderStateMixin** { }

Answer (score 0):

```
//I had the same problem, to solve it I just added

with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

//and finally add the following

TabController? _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _tabController = TabController(initialIndex: 0, length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is even simpler, before `Scaffold`, add the `DefaultTabController` Widget

Example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
```